# Stop sj:datepicker from opening Struts2

Tags: struts2, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have following `<sj:datepicker>` :

```
<sj:datepicker
    id="dateFrom_id%{index}"  
    name="billingItems[%{index}].dateFrom" 
    value="%{billingItems[#index].dateFrom}"  
    displayFormat="dd.mm.yy"
    cssClass="customDatePicker" 
    buttonImage="/images/icons/calendar-blue.png"
    parentTheme="css_custom"
    firstDay="1"
    onBeforeTopics="beforeShow"
/>
```

and the following `beforeShow` topic:

```
$.subscribe('beforeShow', function(event, data) {

    if($(event.originalEvent.input).attr('readonly')){
        // ned to stop event
    }
});
```

How can I stop the event from propagating. I have tried:

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: AFAIK no easy way to achieve this with current version of struts2-jquery-plugin. Wait for update or use plain jQuery.

Comment: update is not a solution in my project ? i find a way:If i knowingly cause error, for example call a non existing method event.callNonExistingMethode();  then the propagation stops, but that is not a good solution. Any other solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` instead use only `stopImmediatePropagation();`

Try this

```
$.subscribe('beforeShow', function(event, data) {

if($(event.originalEvent.input).attr('readonly')=="readonly"){
     stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert('hi');
}
});
```

**alert line will not execute.**

Also do not forget to use readonly="true" in your < sj:datepicker ... /> . For example

```
<sj:datepicker
id="dateFrom_id"  
name="dateFrom" 
value="%{'today'}"
displayFormat="dd.mm.yy"
buttonImage="images/icon/Calendar-Blue.png"
cssClass="customDatePicker" 
firstDay="1"
onBeforeTopics="beforeShow"
readonly="true"
/>
```